# What is the correct way of migrating a Magento installation from WAMP to an online domain?

Tags: magento, migration, wamp

Say i have a [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/) installation which i've configured and developed on a [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com) server (perhaps also adding products, etc.), what is the correct way to migrate this to an online domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had pretty good luck with this approach when I did it.  The WAMP install was on my own box so I didn't use SSH on that side.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/moving_magento_to_another_server

I did have a couple errors related to the new domain that their help desk were able to resolve by modifying a couple entries in my .htaccess file.  But other than that it was pretty seemless.

I've also done a full backup/restore by simply copying the entire contents from one box to the other.  Copying up the MySQL DB, and then I reran the install procedure by simply deleting the app/etc/local.xml file (which forces Magento to run re-install scripts).

The script asks you for the location of the DB, passwords, etc... all the data, products, order history etc, survives a reinstall.

Oh, and make sure to clear your cache/cache folders before you move everything.  That saves a lot of head-aches later and reduces the size of files you have to copy.